# Documentation of SortDescription concerning null or empty parameters

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, collectionviewsource

I'm applying a sort to an `ICollectionView` by using a `SortDescription`.

My data are strings so I've naively assumed that I could use `null` or `""` for the `propertyName` parameter as there is no property to provide; so I've done:

```
view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(null, ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

And it works as expected with both `null` and `""`.

Later I've checked [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.sortdescription.sortdescription.aspx) and found that:

```
The propertyName parameter cannot be null
The propertyName parameter cannot be empty
```

In both cases it should throw an exception.

So am I missing something or a MS summer intern hasn't done its job correctly?

Comment: This is weird indeed. Let's cross our fingers and hope that another MS summer intern read this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the documentation is wrong. You can find the implementation [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/src/Base/System/ComponentModel/SortDescription.cs#fb072871ec88a591)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the source code. Strangely in VS when I "Go To Definition" I see incorrect XML doc, with exceptions documented.